An equivalent characterization of $\mathcal{S}'$ as distributions on the sphere
I originally asked this question on Mathstack Exchange, but I think this question is more suitable for here.
Please let me know if that is not the case so that I can delete or edit this post.
Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be $n$-dimensional Euclidean space and $S^n$ be the $n$-sphere.
If we fix a point $x \in S^n$, the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ can be identified with the subspace of $C^\infty(S^n)$ whose elements have vanishing derivatives of all orders at $x$, according to this post. Let us denote this subspace as $\mathcal{D}_x(S^n)$.
Now, consider $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the space of tempered distributions. Then, of course, you can just say that $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is identified with the dual space of $\mathcal{D}_x(S^n)$. However, it would be nice to have a more detailed description. That is,

Is there any explicit characterization of tempered distributions as distributions on $S^n$, just like identifying $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\mathcal{D}_x(S^n)$?

I would deeply appreciate any answer or reference.

By the way, we need to specify carefully the map of $\mathbb R^n$ to the sphere, to be sure that the metric aspects suit our purposes. That is, it's not just a topological one-point compactification, but needs to be smooth, certainly, and "polynomial"... in a suitable sense so that vanishing to infinite order at infinity is equivalent to faster-than-(inverse)-polynomial decay.

I have always had the stereographic projection in mind, which is clearly smooth.

... yes, stereographic projection is smooth, and, significantly, has the relevant metric properties! :)

@paulgarrett So, could you provide any answer (or insight) with the stereographic projection assumed?

Isaac, I will write something explicit about this tomorrow, when I have time...

@paulgarrett Thank you!

It is not quite clear to me what you are looking for but it seems to me that theorem V on p. 238 of my edition of Schwartz does the trick.  A distribution is tempered if and only if it is the restriction to euclidean $n$-space, regarded as an open subset of the $n$-sphere (as in your post), of a distribution on the sphere (my translation and reformulation).  This is in chapter VII  par. 4.

@terceira could you tell me which book you are referring to?

"My edition of Schwartz"?

L. Schwartz, Théorie des Distributions, Hermann, 1978.

@terceira I have always looked for English translation of this book, but it does not seeem to exist...Well, I will try my best to read through the original text. Thank you for your reference.

Well, this result follows immediately from the one you quote (which is theorem II on p. 235 in the same reference) via the Hahn-Banach theorem).

@terceira I mean that it would be nice to have English translation of the whole book, since it contains many good ideas and insights.

Again, since the metric (not merely topological or differential) aspects of a characterization of Schwartz functions as vanishing to infinite order at infinity needs a specific map of $\mathbb R^n$ to a one-point compactification:
One appropriate map is the geometrically obvious
$x \to ({x\over \sqrt{1+|x|^2}}, {1\over \sqrt{1+|x|^2}})$ With this, it is pretty easy (if laborious) to check that the Schwartz space is indeed the collection of smooth functions vanishing to infinite order at infinity.
But/and the particulars of the formula are not essential: anything differing only by smooth-polynomial-etc will accomplish the same.
The question about characterizing tempered distributions in this way seems to me to have a negative answer... in the sense that this viewpoint does not enhance our understanding of tempered distributions. I may be mistaken, of course, and would be interested to hear other ideas... Edit: there is the "natural" (and correct) assertion that every tempered distribution is a restriction of a distribution on the sphere, basically by Hahn-Banach, since the TVS topology on Schwartz functions is indeed the subspace topology from test functions on the sphere. Further, the space of tempered distributions is the quotient of the space of all distributions by the distributions supported at infinity (which are linear combinations of Dirac delta and its derivatives...).
